# Boundary element method (BEM) in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Please is there any mathematica codes for solving PDEs say Laplace or Poisson Equations by using boundary elements method?

Best regards,

Comment: There is no build-in support for BEM in Mathematica as far as I know. There is this old package https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/3802/  `we introduce two new Mathematica packages for solving problems arising from the engineering field, by using the Boundary Elements Method (BEM)`

Comment: Dear Nasser, many thanks for your super fast response, how can I got the codes for above?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. it is old as you can see, from 1997. May be you contact the author at https://personales.unican.es/iglesias/  or wait to see if someone knows of more recent packages. It used to be that library.worlfram will have the software or paper there on same page, but I do not think this site is being maintained for long time now.

Comment: The article is  available at https://www.witpress.com/elibrary/wit-transactions-on-engineering-sciences/15/7917

Comment: This would be a nice addition; if you get around to write / find a package I'd very much like to see it. I'd appreciate if you could @ ping me.

Comment: Dear Naseer and Alex many thanks for your comments, I think it will be very useful for researchers around the world to have BEM codes using mathematica....Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a working code that I translated from MATLAB code. I improved it a little, but I didn’t finish it to the end. I give it as it is. Code BEM to solve the Laplace  equation in a rectangle

```
N0 = NO = 20;(*the number of boundary elements per side*)
NN = 4*NO;
dl = 1/NO;
Do[ xb[i] = (i - 1)*dl; 
  yb[i] = 0;
  xb[NO + i] = 1;
  yb[NO + i] = xb[i];
  xb[2*NO + i] = 1 - xb[i];
  yb[2 NO + i] = 1;
  xb[3*NO + i] = 0;
  yb[3*NO + i] = 1 - xb[i];, {i, 1, NO}];

xb[NN + 1] = xb[1];
yb[NN + 1] = yb[1];

Do[xm[i] = 0.5*(xb[i] + xb[i + 1]);
  ym[i] = 0.5*(yb[i] + yb[i + 1]);
  lg[i] = Sqrt[(xb[i + 1] - xb[i])^2 + (yb[i + 1] - yb[i])^2];
  nx[i] = (yb[i + 1] - yb[i])/lg[i];
  ny[i] = (-xb[i + 1] + xb[i])/lg[i];, {i, 1, NN}];


(*boundary conditions*)
Do[BCT[i] = 0;
  BCV[i] = 0;, {i, 1, NN}];

Do[BCT[i] = 1;
  BCV[i] = 0;, {i, 1, N0}];

Do[BCT[i] = 0;
  BCV[i] = Cos[Pi*ym[i]];, {i, N0 + 1, 2 N0}];

Do[BCT[i] = 1;
  BCV[i] = 0;, {i, 2 N0 + 1, 3 N0}];

(*end*)
Do[BC[m] = 0;
 Do[A[k] = lg[k]^2;
  B[k] = 2*lg[k]*(-ny[k]*(xb[k] - xm[m]) + nx[k]*(yb[k] - ym[m]));
  E0[k] = (xb[k] - xm[m])^2 + (yb[k] - ym[m])^2;
  D0[k] = Sqrt[Abs[4*A[k]*E0[k] - B[k]^2]];
  BA[k] = B[k]/A[k];
  EA[k] = E0[k]/A[k];
  If[ 4*A[k]*E0[k] - B[k]^2 == 0,
   PF1[k] = 
    0.5*lg[k]*(Log[lg[k]] + (1 + 0.5*BA[k])*Log[Abs[1 + 0.5*BA[k]]] - 
       0.5*BA[k]*Log[Abs[0.5*BA[k]]] - 1), 
   PF1[k] = 
    0.25*lg[k]*(2*(Log[lg[k]] - 1) - 
       0.5*BA[k]*Log[Abs[EA[k]]] + (1 + 0.5*BA[k])*
        Log[Abs[1 + BA[k] + EA[k]]] + (D0[k]/
          A[k])*(ArcTan[D0[k], 2*A[k] + B[k]] - ArcTan[D0[k], B[k]]))];
  If[ 4*A[k]*E0[k] - B[k]^2 == 0, PF2[k] = 0, 
   PF2[k] = 
    lg[k]*(nx[k]*(xb[k] - xm[m]) + ny[k]*(yb[k] - ym[m]))/
      D0[k]*(ArcTan[D0[k], 2*A[k] + B[k]] - ArcTan[D0[k], B[k]])];
  F1[k] = PF1[k]/Pi;
  F2[k] = PF2[k]/Pi;

  If[ k == m,
   del = 1, del = 0];
  If[ BCT[k] == 0,
   AB[m, k] = -F1[k], AB[m, k] = F2[k] - 0.5*del];
  If[ BCT[k] == 0, BC[m] = BC[m] + BCV[k]*(-F2[k] + 0.5*del),
   BC[m] = BC[m] + BCV[k]*F1[k]];, {k, 1, NN}];, {m, 1, NN}]

NAC = NN;

ABM = SparseArray[{i_, j_} -> AB[i, j], {NN, NN}];


BCM = SparseArray[{i_} -> BC[i], {NN}]; Z = LinearSolve[ABM, BCM];


Do[
  If [BCT[m] == 0,
   phi[m] = BCV[m], phi[m] = Z[[m]]];
  If[ BCT[m] == 0, dphi[m] = Z[[m]],
   dphi[m] = BCV[m]];, {m, 1, NN}];




sol = ParallelTable[sum = 0; Do[A[i] = lg[i]^2;
    B[i] = 2*lg[i]*(-ny[i]*(xb[i] - xi) + nx[i]*(yb[i] - eta));
    E1[i] = (xb[i] - xi)^2 + (yb[i] - eta)^2;
    D1[i] = Sqrt[Abs[4*A[i]*E1[i] - B[i]^2]];
    BA[i] = B[i]/A[i];
    EA[i] = E1[i]/A[i];
    If[ 4*A[i]*E1[i] - B[i]^2 == 0,
     PF1[i] = 
      0.5*lg[i]*(Log[lg[i]] + (1 + 0.5*BA[i])*
          Log[Abs[1 + 0.5*BA[i]]] - 0.5*BA[i]*Log[Abs[0.5*BA[i]]] - 
         1), PF1[i] = 
      0.25*lg[i]*(2*(Log[lg[i]] - 1) - 
         0.5*BA[i]*Log[Abs[EA[i]]] + (1 + 0.5*BA[i])*
          Log[Abs[1 + BA[i] + EA[i]]] + (D1[i]/
            A[i])*(ArcTan[D1[i], (2*A[i] + B[i])] - 
            ArcTan[D1[i], B[i]]))];
    If[ 4*A[i]*E1[i] - B[i]^2 == 0, PF2[i] = 0, 
     PF2[i] = 
      lg[i]*(nx[i]*(xb[i] - xi) + ny[i]*(yb[i] - eta))/
        D1[i]*(ArcTan[D1[i], 2*A[i] + B[i]] - ArcTan[D1[i], B[i]])]; 
    sum = sum + phi[i]*PF2[i] - dphi[i]*PF1[i];, {i, 1, NN}];
   {xi, eta, sum/Pi}, {xi, .1, .9, .1}, {eta, 0.1, .9, .1}];
```

Equivalent FEM Code

```
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Cos[Pi y], x == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0]};
bc1 = NeumannValue[0, y == 0 || y == 1] ;
U = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == bc1, bc}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] reg]

sol1 = Table[{x, y, U[x, y]}, {x, 0.1, .9, .1}, {y, 0.1, .9, .1}];
```

Comparison of two solutions and the solution itself

```
dsol = Flatten[sol - sol1, 1][[All, 3]];
{ListPlot[dsol], 
 ContourPlot[U[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Dear Alex great job well done, can we evaluate the relative errors to see FEM or BEM is better with less  error?

Comment: There is no point in deciding which method is more accurate. This is just an example of BEM for pedagogical purposes, which I worked on for a couple of hours. Whereas Mathematica FEM with `NDSolve` is a high-tech product that took several years. On this simple problem, we see that the solutions differ by a maximum of `-0.000872012` at `sol=-0.505865` and `sol1=-0.504993`.

Comment: Thank you Alex, some researchers said BEM better than FEM, that why I was asked to evaluate the error.....Best regards

Comment: For 3D problems, BEM is more accurate than FEM with equal split (I tested this). But on 2d there can be equal opportunities, as in this example. The accuracy of the BEM also depends on the accuracy of the integration method.

Comment: Many thanks Alex.

Comment: @user62716 See also my answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513834/current-density-in-a-3d-loop-discretising-a-model/515657#515657

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am more than happy to discuss that with you... Best regards

Comment: @user62716 You are welcome. I will publish comparative tests for BEM and FEM in 3D after all.

Comment: It will be fine and I am waiting Dr.Alex, I do not know if I can send you my e-mail here for future research collaboration .....Best regards